# div will not scale with window size, is the jquery stopping it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

All the images on my page are positioned and sized using percentages. This is my first attempt at a fully responsive page. Everything scales down as I adjust the window size except for this one div that holds the testimonials, which also happens to be the only part of the page with jquery that crossfades the testimonials. I opened in IE and the jquery was blocked, so I tried adjusting the window size and it worked correctly. How do I fix this? I tried doing the same thing with css only but it was much more complicated and it also mentioned that it wasn't completely browser compatible.

Here's some code, but I have no idea which part is even the problem. I made it live for you. The images are huge, I need to resize, forgive the amateur hour please.

```
.slideshow {    
background-image:url('images/bubble.png');
background-size:cover;
position:absolute;
top:60%;
right:1%;
}

.slideshow img {
width:100%; 
}


<div class="slideshow" style="width:20%">
    <img src="images/testimonialzack.png" />
    <img src="images/testimonialerica.png" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.slideshow').cycle({
    fx: 'fade' 
});
});
</script>
```

www.pseudoburbia.com/indextest.html

Comment: Please add the least amount of code that represents your problem to your question.

Comment: right, so shouldn't it scale with the window size?

Answer (score 0):

put width 100% on images and it looked like that solved the problem

Comment: I tried using inline css on the images and that didn't do anything, I already have 100% on the images in css. what did you do exactly?

Comment: the javascript is creating its own box. the slideshow div is set to a Px width if you change that to a percentage the slideshow background image becomes scalable, but this image is disassociated from the text, put the text into the background image you have and make sure to make the text a percentage as well. if your still having problems after this letting us see the jquery you used would be helpful.

Comment: The div is not set to a px width, it is set to 20%. There is not text, only a background image and word images that sit on top and transition. I can't put the text into the background image without then having to rely on some kind of css to make the transition effect - which I have already tried. I edited and added the jquery, the link in my post is still good too - you can see the whole thing in action.